# iPhoneカメラから輝度情報を得たい

Tags: swift, swift5, camera

iPhoneカメラからのリアルタイムの映像を用いて動きの回数（腕立ての回数）をカウントするアプリを作成したいです．

なかなか輝度情報を扱う方法が見つからないためわかる方いらっしゃれば教えていただけると幸いです．

Comment: 検索して「輝度」という単語が載ってそうなのがこれら。[Metalを利用したAR体験の表示](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/arkit/displaying_an_ar_experience_with_metal/), [Apply custom camera filters on live camera preview - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46998489/9014308), 前記の勝手翻訳？版 [swift - ライブカメラプレビューでカスタムカメラフィルターを適用する-Swift](https://cloud6.net/so/swift/2255216) 何か参考になるかも。

Answer (score 0):

https://qiita.com/koogawa/items/e0b3862c0fbdf97b579f
これではダメでしょうか?

> 画面輝度は次のように取得できます。
>
> `Objective-C`:
>
> ```
> CGFloat brightness = [UIScreen mainScreen].brightness;
> ```
>
> 0.0〜1.0 の値が返ってきます。数値が増えるほど明るくなります。

ちなみに、`Swift`の場合はこうです。
`Swift`:

```
var brightness: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.brightness
```

> 画面輝度＝周りの明るさなので、輝度が高ければユーザが明るい場所にいると判断することもできそうです。
> ただ、中には画面輝度を固定に設定しているユーザもいるので、一概にこの基準が当てはまるとは限りません。

だそうです。